# Scrolling is jagged and immediately stops on iOS

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I'm working on my personal website. There's this weird problem that on my iOS device (I don't have any other mobile devices to test this on) scrolling seems bugged. It's not smooth, and it immediately stops when you lift your finger off the screen.

As I have no clue where the problem might be, I'll not post the entire code of my website. It is live at [nielshak.com](http://nielshak.com).

Things I tried: removing all JS from my website (to exclude any JS is tampering with scroll behaviour), removing all :hover css selectors (to exclude that any hover elements might tamper with scrolling) and adding -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch to the css.
I'm at a total loss here. I really appreciate all help!

Edit: I still have no insights on this. Is there anyone out there with further suggestions?

Comment: FYI the scroll is fine on an (slightly old) Android device, some of the elements are out of place, but I think it's rather due to my browser not up to date, as I've had the same problem on other websites recently. Precising the model of your phone could maybe help, though

Comment: Thank, good to know! I'm using an iPhone SE. A friend of mine has an X and experiences the same issue. Looks like it may be iOS related.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try `-webkit-overflow-scrolling`?. Add `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` to `page-wrapper`.